# No database selected error when using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting `No database selected` error.  I am not sure if there is a way to check if something is being blocked.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];

    $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

    if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv")
    {
      $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
      $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
      {
        $sql = "INSERT into thingy(thingr,thing1,thing2) " .
            "values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      }
      fclose($handle);
      echo "Successfully Imported";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Invalid File";
    }   
  } 
?>
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' >

  Import File : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>

</form>
```

Comment: user ctrl+k instead of `>` in beaning of every line

Comment: show the exact error message

Comment: Have you opened a connection to a database server and selected the database to use?

Comment: question you asked is not a real/constructive  question we are waiting for your replay ...other wise counting is on

Comment: it isnt issue of xamp aslo ...

Comment: What would the issue be then? Its so strange because it did work with the other connection file. I tried over and over and now it will not work.. However if I do try it written this way even if it is in a require or includes it works just fine. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I am having the same problem with xampp7. If I switch back to xampp with php 5.6 it's fine. What's worse is it is impossible to find any real answers, since all the questions related to "no database selected" give answers like, "you have to select the database first." Well, duh. For me it is only happening on ajax calls, and so far my debugging has led me to believe it has something to do with the session. Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
  $conn_str = mysql_connect('localhost', 'yout_user_id', 'your_user_password');
  if (!$conn_str) {
    die('Not connected  to the database: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db_selected = mysql_select_db('your_database_name', $conn_str);
  if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can\'t use your_database_name : " . mysql_error());
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];

    $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

    if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv")
    {

      $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
      $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
      {
        $sql = "INSERT into thingy(thingr,thing1,thing2) " . 
            "values(\"$data[0]\",\"$data[1]\",\"$data[2]\")";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
       }
       fclose($handle);
       echo "Successfully Imported";
     }
     else
     {
       echo "Invalid File";
     }   
   }
?>

<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' >

  Import File : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: I was using the same includes on each page and nothing... yours did work.... ? I'm not sure why

Comment: @user1474885:Whenever you get stuck with such thing,for debugging put an echo to keep a track of the execution. The error message maybe be difficult to interpret sometimes. BTW,what was the error message that you were receiving?

Comment: The exact error that showed up  was - No database selected... By put a echo..Can you give me a example please?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to check would be if your database is actually connected using `mysql_connect`.

Comment: you should wait for the reply in comment what Robbie asked

Comment: sorry i didn't state it above.. must have accidently deleted it. But yes I did have a connection.. see below.. not sure what the difference is from mine and someone elses.. And why it worked just fine and I never changed anything else with the connection

Answer (score 1):

you need to connect to mysql first and then select a database before start executing sql queries

try this.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];

         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

         if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv")
         {

             $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
             $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                $sql = "INSERT into thingy(thingr,thing1,thing2) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
                mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
             }

             fclose($handle);
             echo "Successfully Imported";
         }
         else
        {
             echo "Invalid File";
         }   
    }

    ?>

   <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' >

       Import File : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>

    </form>
```

Comment: I did have a connection.. please see below

Answer (score 0):

You need `mysql_select_db("your_dbName", $link_identifier)` for selecting database..

[Find more details about `mysql_select_db` at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

Also, start using *mysqli* functions or *PDO* statements..

Comment: you should wait for the reply in comment what Robbie asked

Comment: sorry i forgot to include this in my post. But I did have this. please see above

Comment: Well it was working with - $hostname_c = "localhost"; $database_c = "thing5"; $username_c = "root"; $password_c = ""; $datac = mysql_pconnect($hostname_c, $username_c, $password_c) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); what I find even stranger is that this worked the other day and then stopped.. but then i added in user1219539 and it works wonderfully that way. I don't understand why it worked then stopped like I had it before.. what could cause this Can anyone explain? –

Comment: see it will work as long as you are making a valid connection to your mysql server say with `$datac = mysql_connect($hostname_c, $username_c, $password_c) or die(mysql_error());`  and are selecting the database with something like `mysql_select_db($database_c);` Also, as you are starting out things, so you better start with mysqli or PDO and leave mysql things aside..Also, you need the connection code/file included in each php script where ever you are trying to do something with the database..

Comment: Rishi kalia thanks I know about the pdo and mysql jazz.. As for the connecting I don't think you understand what I am getting at I had all the right information.. I was making a fine connection.. then it just stop working.. I was wondering if there is was same to tell with xammpp or what exactly caused the problem... I don't understand why it decides to work sometimes and doesnt want to work other times.. Its working fine now.. Is there anyway of getting more info of what caused this?